# How do I change the value of a label for input file tag to a file's name when the file is picked?

Tags: php, jquery, label

This is the relevant code for the label and file input field.

```
<?php

require "../konekcija/konekcija.php";
require "../modeli/zadatak.php";

[...]

if (isset($_POST["button"])) {
    $naziv = trim($_POST["naziv"]);
    $kategorija = trim($_POST["kategorija"]);
    $opis = trim($_POST["opis"]);

    $tempime = $_FILES["slika"]["name"];
    $ime = time()."_".$_FILES["slika"]["name"];
    $target = "../slike/".$ime;
    
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["slika"]["tmp_name"], $target);

    Zadatak::dodaj($naziv, $korisnik, $kategorija, $opis, $ime, $konekcija))
}

?>

[...]

<body>
    <div>
        <?php include("header.php"); ?>
    </div>

    <div class="container_wrapper">
        <form method="post" action="" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <h4>Slika</h4>
            <label for="slika" id="slikalabel" name="slikalabel" class="inputslika"><span>Unesi sliku</span></label>
            <input type="file" name="slika" id="slika" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" value="" style="display: none" onchange="promeniLabelu()">
        </form>
    </div>

</body>
</html>

<script>  

function promeniLabelu() {
    $(".inputslika").change(function() {
        $('#slikalabel span').text("<?php echo $tempime; ?>").change;        
    });
}
```

I'm trying to change the field's name when the file is uploaded so that, for example, when the user uploads a picture with the filename "nature.jpg", the label changes to that instead of "Unesi sliku" which is on display by default.

I wrote a function for `onchange` on the input field, but it doesn't seem to be working with this code. It works with a regular String value though. What could be the problem?

Comment: Use a listener for the `change` event when the user selects a file.

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with this. Since this is client-side, you must do it with JavaScript.

Comment: Does it have to be JavaScript or can I use JQuery? @Barmar

Comment: jQuery IS JavaScript.

Comment: Change `oninput` to `onchange`

Comment: The `onchange` change didn't work with the code I had. I've updated the question with the new code. Should I go back to the code I had or is this better?

Comment: The function shouldn't call `.change()`. That's already being done by using `onchange`. The function should just do `$('#slikalabel span').text("<?php echo $tempime; ?>")`

Comment: @Barmar That doesn't seem to do anything, even when I put in `$('#slikalabel span').text("SOME TEXT");`

Comment: Works here: https://jsfiddle.net/barmar/2casx31r/1/ I had to remove `style="display: none;"` so I could change the input.

Comment: Note that `<?php echo $tempime; ?>` won't work to get the filename the user selected. That variable is set when the form is submitted and the page reloads the next time, not while the user is interacting.